# Is it possible to automatically log in in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, automatic-logon

Would it be possible to set up Windows XP to automatically log in a user after a reboot?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Click **Start**, and then click **Run**.
2. In the **Open** box, type **control userpasswords2**, and then click **OK**.
3. Clear the "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer" check box, and then click **Apply**.
4. In the **Automatically Log On** window, type the password in the **Password** box, and then retype the password in the **Confirm Password** box.
5. Click **OK** to close the **Automatically Log On** window, and then click **OK** to close the **User Accounts** window.

Comment: +1: I thought it worth mentioning that this works for Vista also. Thanks Molly :)

Comment: In addition to this, you can download the free tool called [Auto Logon & Lock](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Auto-Logon-Lock-Download-145147.html) which automatically locks the screen while loading everything in the background.  Very clever and it works...

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to Molly's solution would be to use [TweakUI](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/c/a/fca6767b-9ed9-45a6-b352-839afb2a2679/TweakUiPowertoySetup.exe), part of [Microsoft's PowerToys for Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx).

> (TweakUI) gives you access to system settings that are not exposed in the Windows XP default user interface, including mouse settings, Explorer settings, taskbar settings, and more.

The reason I mention it is that not only can you enable automatic login, but the tool exposes a wealth of other system options which can easily be changed with the GUI.  I think it's an important tool that all power users should at least consider downloading and looking at *once*...

Comment: +1, because on my system, part of a company domain, the step-by-step solution given by Molly did not expose the settings outlined in step 3, but TweakUI worked

Answer (score 0):

There is also a program that lets you adjust autologin called [TweakNow Winsecret 2011](http://www.tweaknow.com/WinSecret.php)

It allows you to adjust your settings and autologin without using alot of resources.