# Is it possible to have a delay for auto login in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, login

As [explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/40117/is-it-possible-to-automatically-login-in-winxp/40119#40119) you can set auto login for a user account in Windows XP by setting the right option in `control userpasswords2`.

My question is now: Is it possible to have this autologin delayed - say 10 or 20 seconds - to allow another user to login instead?

We have this family PC with a 80/10/10 usage pattern, so we think it would make sense to have the 80% user login automatically and allow the 10% users as small delay to login instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delayed : No, but disabled once : Yes.

From [MSGina.dll Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378750%28VS.85%29.aspx) :

> If the SHIFT key is held down during
>   the boot process, MSGina.dll will
>   ignore the AutoAdminLogon key value
>   and prompt the user for identification
>   and authentication information
>   interactively.

You can use this method to temporarily disable automatic logon at startup, by simply pressing and holding the Shift key during the boot.

Once the logon screen is displayed, do **not** continue to hold the shift key, as this will disable some startup programs ([source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457123.aspx)).

Comment: harrymc - "Once the logon screen is displayed, do not continue to..." : As I understand the logon-shift-key description you linked to, this applies to the time *after* the user entered his password and the logon itself is in progress?

Comment: It would really be interesting to know when "during the boot process" actually starts and ends.

Comment: Yes, the Shift also plays a (different) part during the logon process after the logon screen (just mentioned it for completeness). The duration for pressing: The best answer I can give is after the BIOS boot part and before the logon screen. You may have to experiment.

Answer (score 3):

While I am not aware of such an option,

You may want to look into fast user switching: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279765/en-us

This would enable your main user to autologon and stay logged in while the other users just switch while they are using the computer.