# How to do silent auto-login?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to automatically login in WinXP?](https://superuser.com/questions/40117/is-it-possible-to-automatically-login-in-winxp)

I always use only one account on my computer. I have a lot of programs in auto-start and I do need them all. The problem is that they take some time to load (for example flash game on facebook).

is there any way to do auto-login on the account and lock screen so no-one else can use my account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Run `control userpasswords2` to setup auto-logon (by unchecking the box)
2. Setup a short-cut in All Programs\Run or the Run registry key or use a sheduled task to run the command `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation` to lock your computer right after log-on.

Comment: Holding down the SHIFT key during login will disable startup scripts.  I'm not sure about scheduled tasks, though.