# Secure way of doing auto-login & locking the screen

Tags: windows, windows-xp, login, auto-login, lock-screen

I had one answer here about how to do auto-login & sceen locking
[How to do silent auto-login?](https://superuser.com/questions/352200/how-to-do-silent-auto-login)

however it is not secure, how to do that more secure way?

P.S. I tried the free tool called Auto Logon & Lock, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Related: [Windows 7: Automatially login and lock](http://superuser.com/questions/352616/windows-7-automatially-login-and-lock)

Answer (score 4):

Change your *logon shell* at `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon → Shell (REG_SZ)` from Explorer to a program that first calls `LockWorkStation()`, followed by starting of the real `Explorer.exe`.

Or do it even earlier by changing `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon → Userinit (REG_SZ)` to a wrapper for Userinit.exe.

([Do not use `rundll32`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043) for locking, though. Write something in C# or Python or whatever else.)